# Getting image urls from a Volusion store csv export

Tags: e-commerce, volusion

I am creating a Volusion integration to allow users to import products into our site from their Volusion store.  I am using csv instead of the API, since the API is only enabled for stores with plans of a certain level.

In the Volusion products export there is a `photourl` field for all products, but only one url is listed.  What if a product has 2, 3, or more photos?

I am aware that there is a naming convention with Volusion products, and all products are stored in a single directory.  However this doesn't really help me learn whether a second, third, fourth, etc. image exists for a product.  Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone else has this issue, I found this from another shopping cart that says only first image is migrated http://support.supadupa.me/customer/portal/articles/1216271-can-i-import-my-products-from-volusion-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the standard export will only give you the main photo URL

For example:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/v/vspfiles/photos/SKU001-1.jpg
http://www.yoursite.com/v/vspfiles/photos/SKU002-1.jpg
http://www.yoursite.com/v/vspfiles/photos/SKU003-1.jpg
```

Do you have the capability of calling a GET on -2.jpg, -3.jpg, etc for each product, looking for a 200 or 404 until you've found all the images for each product?

Comment: Ok thanks...that's why I like Shopify, BigCommerce, & WooCommerce more